# Nao cross_compilation libmpfr.so.1 error

Tags: cross-compilation, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to cross-compile for the Nao following the instructions (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling)

I get the following library error:

/media/external/nao-cross-toolchain-1.10.52/cross/geode/bin/../libexec/gcc/i586-linux/4.3.3/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

That file is no where to be found in the nao-cross-toolchain folder.  I do, however, have libmpfr.so.4 in my /usr/lib directory.  Any suggestions on how to either download the libmpfr.so.1 file or point the compilation to the appropriate location?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12563/nao-cross_compilation-libmpfr.so.1-error/) by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess that you're using Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric), which does not provide libmpfr.so.1 any more. According to [Nao's documentation](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/cpp/install_guide.html), Oneiric is not officially supported by Aldebaran yet. You can still give it a try, but probably some dependencies will be missing.

In the case of libmpfr, you could try to download the package [libmpfr1ldbl from Ubuntu Natty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libmpfr1ldbl), extract it using `dpkg -x` and copy libmpfr.so.1 to /media/external/nao-cross-toolchain-1.10.52/cross/geode/bin/../libexec/gcc/i586-linux/4.3.3 .

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) with karma: 281 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just do: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4 /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.1

This is a bug in the cross-compilation toolchain that occurs with ubuntu 11.04 and later. Never came across it before, because we are still using 10.04 and 10.10 here.
This problem is supposed to be fixed in naoqi 1.12 but unfortunately there are some new issues (like missing log4cxx).

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on 2012-01-12**:
aw, that's another problem. I installed a 32-bit chroot environment for that case. Basically, it should be possible to cross compile with a 64bit system, however I think nobody at Aldebaran tested this. You could try as stefan suggested and download the 32bit version of libmpfr.so.1 and copy to /usr/lib/.

**Comment by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on 2012-01-12**:
Thanks for the suggestion.  That seemed to solve that particular issue.  However, since my machine is a 64 bit computer, now I get the issue:wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64.  I think I'm just going to switch to an older laptop.